# Azure AKS fluxconfig-agent 401 causing unhealthy

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, flux, azure-managed-identity

I have an AKS environment based on the AKS-Construction templates

At some point fluxconfig-agent started reporting unhealthy. I checked the logs and it looks like there is a 401 when it tries to fetch config from  https://eastus.dp.kubernetesconfiguration.azure.com

```
    {"Message":"2022/10/03 17:09:01 URL:\u003e https://eastus.dp.kubernetesconfiguration.azure.com/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/my-aks/provider/Microsoft.ContainerService-managedclusters/clusters/my-aks/configurations/getPendingConfigs?api-version=2021-11-01","LogType":"ConfigAgentTrace","LogLevel":"Information","Environment":"prod","Role":"ClusterConfigAgent","Location":"eastus","ArmId":"/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/my-aks/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedclusters/my-aks","CorrelationId":"","AgentName":"FluxConfigAgent","AgentVersion":"1.6.0","AgentTimestamp":"2022/10/03 17:09:01"}
    {"Message":"2022/10/03 17:09:01 GET configurations returned response code {401}","LogType":"ConfigAgentTrace","LogLevel":"Information","Environment":"prod","Role":"ClusterConfigAgent","Location":"eastus","ArmId":"/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/my-aks/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedclusters/my-aks","CorrelationId":"","AgentName":"FluxConfigAgent","AgentVersion":"1.6.0","AgentTimestamp":"2022/10/03 17:09:01"}  
    {"Message":"2022/10/03 17:09:01 Failed to GET configurations with ResponseCode : {401}","LogType":"ConfigAgentTrace","LogLevel":"Information","Environment":"prod","Role":"ClusterConfigAgent","Location":"eastus","ArmId":"/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/my-aks/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedclusters/my-aks","CorrelationId":"","AgentName":"FluxConfigAgent","AgentVersion":"1.6.0","AgentTimestamp":"2022/10/03 17:09:01"}
    {"Message":"Error in the getting the Configurations: error {%!s(\u003cnil\u003e)}","LogType":"ConfigAgentTrace","LogLevel":"Error","Environment":"prod","Role":"ClusterConfigAgent","Location":"eastus","ArmId":"/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/my-aks/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedclusters/my-aks","CorrelationId":"","AgentName":"FluxConfigAgent","AgentVersion":"1.6.0","AgentTimestamp":"2022/10/03 17:09:01"}
    {"Message":"2022/10/03 17:09:01 \"Errorcode: 401, Message Unauthorized client credentials., Target /subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/my-aks/provider/Microsoft.ContainerService-managedclusters/clusters/my-aks/configurations/getPendingConfigs\"","LogType":"ConfigAgentTrace","LogLevel":"Information","Environment":"prod","Role":"ClusterConfigAgent","Location":"eastus","ArmId":"/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/my-aks/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedclusters/my-aks","CorrelationId":"","AgentName":"FluxConfigAgent","AgentVersion":"1.6.0","AgentTimestamp":"2022/10/03 17:09:01"}
```

Is anyone here familiar with how fluxconfig-agent authenticates and what might cause a 401 here?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to have went away for now after upgrading my AKS cluster and nodes to latest Kubernetes version.